# C# Media Player Playlist

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

I am trying to make a media player in C#. I want to make a playlist that contains the song name and the length of the song. The code I tried was:

```
private void BtnOpenFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "MP3 Audio File (*.mp3)|*.mp3|Windows Media File (*.wma)|*.wma|WAV Audio File (*.wav)|*.wav";
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;

    if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        files = openFileDialog.SafeFileNames;
        paths = openFileDialog.FileNames;

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (string track in paths)
            {
                WMPLib.IWMPMedia media = this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(track);
                length = media.durationString;
            }

            lstPlaylist.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[i] + length));
        }
    }
}
```

But it shows me the same duration for all songs.

Comment: Why you have two for loops ?

Comment: I did not succeed at all so I tried this way

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) ... because even seasoned pros can get stumped staring at a few lines of code for too long.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void BtnOpenFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "MP3 Audio File (*.mp3)|*.mp3|Windows Media File (*.wma)|*.wma|WAV Audio File (*.wav)|*.wav";
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
    if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        paths = openFileDialog.FileNames;
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++)
        {
            WMPLib.IWMPMedia media = this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(paths[i]);
            length = media.durationString;
            lstPlaylist.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(paths[i] + length));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could benefit from a little explanation since the OP clearly has difficulties understanding program flow and debugging while reading code.